# Getting Started with C# .Net Office 365 APIs

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, office365

I fully expect this is really simple, but I am finding myself overwhelmed and buried in excessive information - Can somebody please point me to, or just write a simple getting started with Office 365 APIs in C# / .Net?

A really specific task I'd like to accomplish is to simply open Visual Studio, create some sort of C# project, and programmatically create a Distribution Group in Office365. I would expect, I just go to NuGet, add some Assembly, and be on my way. But I'm having difficulty finding the right thing to do...

I found this article: [.NET and JavaScript libraries for Office 365 APIs](http://blogs.office.com/2014/05/12/net-and-javascript-libraries-for-office-365-apis/) which suggests I need to install Office 365 API Tools for Visual Studio, but when I did that, I got a web installer with simply hundreds of things in it that I could install - and none of them seemed to be the right thing. I *may* have gotten what I'm looking for by just running that installer and not selecting additional add-ons, but I would never know, because there's nothing suggesting what to do next. Do I need to create a project from a particular template? Go to some new menu under Visual Studio that wasn't there before? Install a NuGet package? I'm lost...

Thanks for pointers.

Side-note: The article I mentioned says to tag stackoverflow questions with `Office365APIs` but when I try that, stackoverflow says *"Creating the new tag Office365APIs requires at least 1500 reputation."* So I can't. And apparently nobody ever has before.

Comment: http://www.pluralsight.com/search/?searchTerm=office365

Answer (score 0):

First off, the best place to get started with Office 365 development is by going to dev.office.com.  In their 'Getting Started" section on connection to APIs, step 2 includes the links to the tools you need.  The link here for the [Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013](http://aka.ms/OfficeDevToolsForVS2013) loads the Web Platform Installer window opened to this tool.  This provides the initial hooks to connect your app to Office 365.

I would also recommend this [post](http://www.andrewconnell.com/azure-ad-asp-net-mvc-walk-through-implementing-adal-owin) from Andrew Connell.  He does a great job of giving you all of the steps needed to create a web application, get it connected to Office 365 and returning data.

There is an Office365-Apps as well, but yes, the office365-api is missing.

Comment: Thanks, but the getting started guide there says Get an Office365 Developer Site, and Set up Azure AD. I'm not looking for a huge complicated enterprisey solution - I just want a program on my computer to make simple changes in my Office365 account.

Comment: Do you already have an Office 365 organization? You can use that instead of a developer site, and Azure AD is included. Azure AD is required for the authentication to work when you use the Office 365 APIs.